# is anyone here have code for multiple inline insert on laravel 5.4 such as multiple user insert,multiple product insert?

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller

I have insert table , per row it can be "append" , so u can **insert** much data than one by one , my question is : is any one here have that tutorial ? Thanks.

[UPDATE] 
I need this view to work can anyone help me ?
===> 
[Here this Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQqvS.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, we do not provide tutorial services. If, after you do more research on the topic, you find yourself with a specific question (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), then please come back and post that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to save multiple related models, you may use the **saveMany** method:

For ex:

```
$post = App\Post::find(1);
$post->comments()->saveMany([
    new App\Comment(['message' => 'A new comment.']),
    new App\Comment(['message' => 'Another comment.']),
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `insert()` method with the following array structure:

```
User::insert([
    ['name' => 'John', 'email' => 'john@site.com'],
    ['name' => 'Lisa', 'email' => 'lisa@site.com'],
    ['name' => 'Josh', 'email' => 'josh@site.com']
]);
```

Or:

```
DB::table('users')->insert([
    ['name' => 'John', 'email' => 'john@site.com'],
    ['name' => 'Lisa', 'email' => 'lisa@site.com'],
    ['name' => 'Josh', 'email' => 'josh@site.com']
]);
```

`insert()` will insert multiple rows with just one query.